# Create an attachment from MVCPortlet - serveResource

Tags: file, download, liferay, portlet

I need to export a .property file when user clicks on a hyperlink. I am using liferay portal 6.1.1. When user clicks on hyperlink, I am making a jquery.get() to the serveResource method which is inside the MyMVCPortlet class. Here the code that always writes the content to response(verified on fiddler) but is not creating a downloadable file.

```
resourceResponse.reset();
resourceResponse.setContentType("text/plain");
resourceResponse.setProperty("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt");

OutputStream out = resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream();
try {
     out.write("key=value".getBytes());
}
catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}           
finally {  
     out.close();//Also tried out.flush(); - dint help
}
```

Do I need to set something on resourceResponse after the write is complete?

I tried different options and got exhausted. The same code on plain java servlet works but not on liferay. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the same code is working for me :) do you want me to share war with you

Comment: Can you post the jQuery part as well? Or may be share more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of `PortletResponseUtil.sendFile()` instead of manual operations on `portletOutputStream`. Eg.

```
PortletResponseUtil.sendFile(resourceRequest, resourceResponse, "test.txt", "key=value".getBytes())
```